# Convert Nested Foreach to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to re-write the following using LINQ

```
foreach (WMCommon.Services.StakeOut.assembly ass in assemblies) 
{
  foreach (var agg in aggregate) 
  {
    if ( agg.catagory.unitActn   == ass.unitActn   &&
         agg.catagory.unitCode   == ass.unitCode   &&
         agg.catagory.unitLength == ass.unitLength
    ) 
    {
      ass.quantity = agg.qty;
    }
  }
}
```

This is as far as I got:

```
assemblies.Where( a => a.quantity = ( aggregate.Where( p => p.catagory.unitActn == a.unitActn && p.catagory.unitCode == a.unitCode && p.catagory.unitLength == a.unitLength).Select(s=>s.qty)));
```

Thank for your help in advance. I am hoping that the LINQ will be much faster than nested FOREACH?

Comment: Shouldn't `a.quantity = ...` be `a.quantity == ...` ?

Comment: When you want to `change/update/assign something` you should not think of `LINQ` that's why the `Q` stands for `Query`. It's used almost to query, select, filter, sort, ... not for changing, updating, assigning... although you can do but it's much the same with foreach, it may also involve the using of `ForEach` static method.

Comment: I highly doubt it will be any faster. If it's performance you're looking for, just add a break; inside the inner foreach loop and that's it.

Comment: @Nick LINQ uses `foreach` inside, so it won't be faster.

Comment: Install resharper and it will suggest you to convert (and convert) almost every line of your code to linq (just kidding, but it will suggest to convert that type of foreach)

Answer (score 7):

> I am hoping that the LINQ will be much faster than nested FOREACH?

In general, LINQ isn't going to improve your performance unless you change how it works.  LINQ is effectively just performing the iterations for you.

In this case, it appears you could just use a join to improve this overall, as this is going to give you the same effect:

```
var query = from WMCommon.Services.StakeOut.assembly ass in assemblies
            join agg in aggregate
            on new { ass.unitActn, ass.unitCode, ass.unitLength } equals new { (agg.catagory.unitActn, agg.catagory.unitCode, agg.catagory.unitLength }
            select new { ass, agg };

foreach(var pair in query)
    pair.ass.quantity = pair.agg.qty;
```

Comment: I have never seen the syntax `on new { ass.unitActn, ass.unitCode, ass.unitLength } equals new { (agg.catagory.unitActn, agg.catagory.unitCode, agg.catagory.unitLength }` to compare multiple items before, I did not know it could handle that. Will that work in all cases (Linq2Objects and Linq2Entities)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, it will.

Comment: nice, this is some kind of `Select first - Assign later` so we can use `LINQ` better :)

Comment: Thanks Reed I will go ahead and try this out to see what the timing I get between the two. As Scott said this is a very cool way of comparing the two. 8-)

Answer (score 1):

Why Linq? it's unlikely to be any faster than what you've got. It's unlikely to be any simpler or easier to read or easier to debug than what you've got.

If you're looking to improve performance, Your nested loops run on O(mn) time, where *m* is the size of the assemblies collection and *n* is the size of the aggregates collection, so basically O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.

Are the collections orderd by the key values? If so, merging the two collections by iterating over the two in lockstep will be a big win. That should bring you down to something like O(n) performance.

If they are not ordered, you can get a win by taking the aggregates collection and converting it into a lookup table like a Dictionary, prior to iterating over the assemblies collection. Then its a straight iteration over assemblies with a presumably fast lookup against the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
assemblies.ForEach(a => a.quantity = (aggregate.Where(p => p.catagory.unitActn == a.unitActn && p.catagory.unitCode == a.unitCode && p.catagory.unitLength == a.unitLength).Select(s=>s.qty)));
```

But mind it it wouldn't be faster

Comment: Isn't that just going to do the same thing as the nested loop? I don't think it'll be any faster.

Comment: It is giving me an error "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<float> to float" Let me take a look which one needs to be converted.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes it will do the same thing, but what i can understand by the question is that the questioner is not able to write it in the form of LINQ query as Where was used instead of ForEach