# How to convert the foreach nested loops to linq format?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Code:

```
foreach (var testItem in testItems.TestChildren)
{
    RadTreeViewItem testParent1 = new RadTreeViewItem();
    parent1.Header = NodeHeader(testItem.TestPath, testItem.TestName, TestSelectedPath, TestProjectData);
    testParent1.TestTag = testItem;
    foreach (var testChild in testItem.TestChildren)
    {
        RadTreeViewItem testChildren = new RadTreeViewItem();
        testChildren.TestHeader = NodeHeader(testChild.TestPath, testChild.TestName, TestSelectedPath, TestProjectData);
        testChildren.TestTag = testChild;
        testParent1.Items.Add(testChildren);
    }
    TestParent.TestItems.Add(testParent1);
}
```

How to convert the above `foreach` nested loops to LINQ? Also, is it possible to further reduce the lines of code and increase the performance and reduce the execution time?

Comment: @Noobacode, I am mainly concern about the performance here.

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18340552/2911047

Comment: @CodingGuru, Thanks for the link. I refer to that but I didn't find a proper solution to how to use the `ItemCollection` when using in `Linq` format.

Comment: @JohnStephen I don't think LINQ solution is possible here. `RadTreeViewItem` class structure is not good enough for LINQ to use it: it uses old-fashioned style with indexer property, `ItemCollection` etc. And if you are worried about performance: LINQ uses `foreach` loops internally, so your code is the same as if you'd use LINQ, or even a bit better, because there is no delegate invocation which would occur with LINQ.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Thankyou very much. I will keep this code as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq is for filtering/selection/projection, not mutation. 
Linq wont give any performance advantages over the code in your question **and** the code would be harder to understand.

Comment: This is correct. You could go further and say LINQ will cause a slight performance hit as it will convert to for loops anyway. The conversion takes time at run-time.