# Simplify nested for loop using linq

Tags: linq, for-loop

I have a list with nested items and I want to move values/node from Category1 to Category2 which are at same level. Doing it using a double for loop takes lot of time.
How can I simplify and make it fast using LINQ?

```
foreach (var item in masterlist) {
    foreach (var item1 in item.Category1) {
        item1.Category1 = item1.Category2;
        item1.Category2 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ won't make this any faster. It could make it shorter in terms of source code, but it won't make it any more efficient. (At least assuming this is in-memory, which I assume is the case here.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Nested Foreach to Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340405/convert-nested-foreach-to-linq)

Answer (score 1):

You still need to use a `foreach` because Linq is only concerned with iteration and querying and should *not* be used to introduce side-effects or actions (this is [why Linq doesn't have a `ForEach` or `Do` extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-there-is-no-foreach-extension-method-on-ienumerable)).

Note that because `item.Category1` is overrwritten inside the loop you need to eagerly-evaluate the Linq expression first.

Try this (assuming your list-item type is named `ListItem`):

```
List<ListItem> allListItems = masterList
    .SelectMany( li => li.Category1 )
    .ToList();

foreach( ListItem item in listItems )
{
    item.Category1 = item.Category2;
    item.Category2 = null;
}
```